# calculate angle of objects in a binary image c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to calculate angle of following cropped image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As7k4.png)

So I developed C#(emguCV & openCV)  code for calculate angle.

It is here,

**For Select pixels of the line,**

```
public ArrayList getLinepixels()
{
   //bi.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
    testPicBox.Image = bi;
    Color pixelColor;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for (int y=0; y <bi.Height; y++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int x = 0; x < bi.Width; x++)
        {

            pixelColor = bi.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (pixelColor.R == 255 && pixelColor.G == 255 && pixelColor.B == 255)
            {
                count++;
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Point p1 = new Point(x, y);
                    list.Add(p1);
                    drawPoint(x, y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int a = list.Count;
       // label2.Text = a.ToString();
    }
```

**For select appropriate pixel cordinates**

```
public ArrayList minimizePixels(ArrayList minimizeArL)
{
    mlist = new ArrayList();
    int minimizeArlCount = minimizeArL.Count;

    for (int i = 2; i < minimizeArlCount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            mlist.Add(minimizeArL[i]);
        }
        else if (i == minimizeArlCount - 2)
        {
            mlist.Add(minimizeArL[i]);
        }
        else if (i == (minimizeArlCount / 2) / 2)
        {
            mlist.Add(minimizeArL[i]);
        }
        else if (i == (minimizeArlCount / 2) + ((minimizeArlCount / 2) / 2))
        {
            mlist.Add(minimizeArL[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Code used for calculating angles**

```
public void calculateAngle(ArrayList angleList)
{
    minimizePixels(getLinepixels());

    int firstRowX = ((Point)mlist[0]).X;
    int firstRowY = ((Point)mlist[0]).Y;

    int secondRowX = ((Point)mlist[1]).X;
    int secondRowY = ((Point)mlist[1]).Y;

    int thirdRowX = ((Point)mlist[2]).X;
    int thirdRowY = ((Point)mlist[2]).Y;

    int fourthRowX = ((Point)mlist[3]).X;
    int fourthRowY = ((Point)mlist[3]).Y;

    double tanTheta;
    double tanAlfa;
    double ang;

    tanTheta = Math.Atan2((Math.Abs(secondRowY - firstRowY)), (Math.Abs(secondRowX - firstRowX)));
    tanAlfa = Math.Atan2((Math.Abs(fourthRowY - thirdRowY)), (Math.Abs(fourthRowX - thirdRowX)));
    ang = (tanTheta + tanAlfa) * (180 / Math.PI);

    metroLabel1_angle.Text = Convert.ToString(ang);
}
```

After implementing above codes program shows some value for angle value but each time it runs it is giving different answers and some times incorrect answers. please help me to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: can you explain which angle exactly your want to determine?

Comment: It's still far from clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I need to calculate angle of the knee in above image.[in the link]